# How can I display a default username value so I stop getting an undefined error?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, ejs

I have a navbar which displays the following on the right side of the screen:

```
Welcome, <%= user %>
```

But in order for me to get the `user` I need to render it like so

```
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  const user = req.user.username;
  res.render("index", user);
});
```

There's obviously a problem with this as if I am not logged in, I'm not able to load the web page at all due to getting an undefined error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')`. Is there a way for me to add a default value to `user` or even display a Sign Up button so I stop getting the TypeError?

Answer (score 1):

simply use [Nullish coalescing assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)

Change:

```
const user = req.user.username;
```

by

```
const user = req.user.username ?? 'default username';
```

doc

Answer (score 0):

I found out how I can fix this. I thought the only way for me to get the `user` value was to render it in my `index.js` file. But by using `user.username` in my `ejs` file I was able to get the same value after logging in and when I'm not logged in, the page loads just fine.

```
<% if (isAuthenticated) { %>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link">
              <%= user.username %>
            </a>
          </li>
       <% } %>
```